# SUMIFS Formula for Ranges with Cells Containing Single or Multiple Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

My Google Sheets workbook contains the following SUMIFS formula:

```
=SUMIFS('Mar 2017'!$J:$J,'Mar 2017'!$K:$K,$A3)
```

That formula works great so long as the range of cells in 'Mar 2017'!$K:$K contain only one date in each cell.

Unfortunately, the folks who set up the workbook sometimes kept track of multiple dates within a single cell. I have separated those dates with line breaks, example…

```
10/10/2017
3/1/2017
9/25/2018
```

…but I am unable to figure out how to write a formula that will sum the value(s) in 'Mar 2017'!$J:$J for cells in 'Mar 2017'!$K:$K that contain the date referenced in $A3 — whether a cell in that column contains a single date, or multiple dates.

Among the many failed attempts I've tried is this one:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER('Mar 2017'!$J:$J, IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT('Mar 2017'!$K:$K, CHAR(10)), TEXT($A3, "mm/dd/yyyy")), FALSE)), 0))
```

Suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use FILTER instead of SUMIFS. Instead of using an equivalence, you can check to find if it matches or not inside a "range" created by splitting the values:

```
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER('Mar 2017'!$J:$J,IFNA(XMATCH('Mar 2017'!$K:$K,SPLIT($A3,CHAR(10)))))))
```

---

UPDATE:

If it's the other way round:

```
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER('Mar 2017'!$J:$J, SEARCH(To_text(A3),TO_TEXT('Mar 2017'!$K:$K)))))
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, @Martín. However, I can get the formula you suggested to SUM a value from 'Mar 2017'!$J:$J only if the date referenced in $A3 is found by itself in a cell in 'Mar 2017'!$K:$K. If the cell in 'Mar 2017'!$K:$K containing the date referenced in $A3 contains more than one date, the formula does not SUM any values from 'Mar 2017'!$J:$J.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you, please try new update!

Comment: Thank you for trying again, @Martín. Your 2nd suggestion works in all the tests I've tried so far, and I have accepted your answer. That said, I had such a headache from trying to troubleshoot this issue yesterday, that I had forgotten to post the 2nd part of my problem (perhaps one reason why my question has so far received only one vote — a down vote). I'll post an updated question perhaps later today that includes the additional issue, and link to it from here. Thank you again for resolving my issue as I had described it!

Comment: I'm glad it worked as expected at least until this point! Good luck with the next part, post the link

Comment: I have posted the full question that I had meant to post here yesterday.

[SUMIF Specific Numbers Within a Formula Based on Position of Date as Text in Adjacent Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76862670/sumif-specific-numbers-within-a-formula-based-on-position-of-date-as-text-in-adj)

If you have the chance to take a look, I would very much appreciate it!