# SUMIF Specific Numbers Within a Formula Based on Position of Date as Text in Adjacent Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am tasked with summing up numerical values based on specific dates. Normally, one might use a SUMIF formula to do this, such as `=SUMIF('Mar 2017'!$K:$K,$A3,'Mar 2017'!$J:$J)`. This works fine as long as there is just one date in each cell in `'Mar 2017'!$K:$K`.

The task becomes much harder if there are multiple dates in certain cells within `'Mar 2017'!$K:$K`, such as…

```
10/10/2017
3/1/2017
9/25/2018
```

…that correspond to cells in `'Mar 2017'!$J:$J` which contain formulas with multiple numbers embedded in them, such as…

```
=416.19+1987.92+1064.14
```

I am trying to come up with a formula that will look for the date referenced in `$A3`, find its match in `'Mar 2017'!$K:$K`, then add to its calculation the number within the formula found in the adjacent cell in `'Mar 2017'!$J:$J` that corresponds to the position the date was found in `'Mar 2017'!$K:$K`.

For instance, let's suppose that `$A3` contains the following date: 3/1/2017. Let's also say that `'Mar 2017'!K6` also contains 3/1/2017 and `'Mar 2017'!J6` contains $1,564.20. In that case, the formula I'm looking for would work just like a regular SUMIF — such as `=SUMIF('Mar 2017'!$K:$K,$A3,'Mar 2017'!$J:$J)` — and would include $1,564.20 in its calculation.

But let's then assume that `'Mar 2017'!K9` contains multiple dates, such as the example I mentioned above…

```
10/10/2017
3/1/2017
9/25/2018
```

…and `'Mar 2017'!J9` contains the following formula: `=416.19+1987.92+1064.14`.

What I need is a formula that will calculate only the number in the second position of the numbers contained in the formula in `'Mar 2017'!J9` — **1987.92** — which corresponds to the 2nd position that 3/1/2017 is found in `'Mar 2017'!K9`.

I've already tried these formulas without success:

```
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER(VALUE(INDEX(SPLIT('Mar 2017'!$J:$J, "+"), , MATCH(TEXT($A3, "mm/dd/yyyy"), SPLIT('Mar 2017'!$K:$K, CHAR(10)), 0))), SPLIT('Mar 2017'!$K:$K, CHAR(10))=TEXT($A3, "mm/dd/yyyy"))))
```

and

```
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER(VALUE(SPLIT('Mar 2017'!$J:$J, "+")), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT($A3, "mm/dd/yyyy"), 'Mar 2017'!$K:$K)), SPLIT('Mar 2017'!$K:$K, CHAR(10))=TEXT($A3, "mm/dd/yyyy"), FALSE))))
```

Any help on this issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,map(J:J,K:K,lambda(j,k,iferror(let(x,split(k,char(10)),y,xmatch(A3,x),hstack(choosecols(iferror(split(formulatext(j),"=+"),j),y),choosecols(x,y)))))),
     sum(ifna(filter(index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2)=A3))))
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressive. I added references to the specific sheet — `=let(Σ,map('Mar 2017'!$J:$J,'Mar 2017'!$K:$K,lambda(j,k,iferror(let(x,split(k,char(10)),y,xmatch(A3,x),hstack(choosecols(iferror(split(formulatext(j),"=+"),j),y),choosecols(x,y)))))), sum(ifna(filter(index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2)=A3))))` — and then your suggestion worked like a charm. Therefore, I have accepted your answer. Thank you.